# How to call UILabel class to apply it to label in Swift?

Tags: swift, uikit

I am trying to create a class contain UILabel properties such as font name, size and color so i made something like this:

```
extension UILabel{
    
    func DesigenLabel(){
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.font = UIFont(name: "mohammad-bold-art-1", size: 20)
        
       
    }
}
```

and I call the class as:

```
self.lbEntranceMessage.DesigenLabel()
```

Nothing change with the label, the font is the same. I have no idea how to sort it out.

Thanks

Comment: Don't create a new label instance in the function, just do `font = ...` or `self.font = ...`. You may also want to subclass `UILabel` instead to set these properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of the UILabel, setting its font and throwing it away.

You would need to set the font on `self.` meaning the `UILabel` this function is called upon e.g.:

```
extension UILabel{
    func desginLabel(){
        self.font = UIFont(name: "mohammad-bold-art-1", size: 20)
    }
}
```